# Mathematica returns some warning and errors instead of Output

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

I have a set of three coupled PDEs. Using NDsolve to get an output plot of my PDE's with the given parameters. As I'm new to Mathematica, I have almost spent two days, but cannot locate the problem with my code, for getting output from  NDsolve of my PDE's.

Can someone help me with this code, I will be very grateful.

```
    My set of PDE' s
\[PartialD]u/\[PartialD]t = D1.\[Del]^2u - uv^2 - uw^2 + F (1 - u);
\[PartialD]v/\[PartialD]t = D2.\[Del]^2v + uv^2 - (F + k1) v;
\[PartialD]w/\[PartialD]t = D3.\[Del]^2w + uw^2 - (F + k2) v;

eqns2[D1_, D2_, 
   D3_] = {u'[t, x] == 
    D1[u[t, x], x, x] - u[t, x]*v[t, x]^2 - u[t, x]*w[t, x]^2 + 
     F (1 - u[t, x]), 
   v'[t, x] == 
    D2[v[t, x], x, x] + u[t, x]*v[t, x]^2 - (F + k1)*v[t, x], 
   w'[t, x] == 
    D3[u[t, x], x, x] + u[t, x]*w[t, x]^2 - (F + k2)*w[t, x], 
   u[t, x] == 0.50, v[t, x] == 0.25, w[t, x] == 0.25};

F = 0.025;
k1 = 0.0043;
k2 = 0.046;
u = 0.618;
v = 0.0767;
w = 0.1860;
sol2 = NDSolve[eqns2[290, 61.443, 11], {u[t], v[t], w[t]}, {t, 0, 20}];

Plot[Evaluate[{u[t], v[t], w[t]} /. sol2], {t, 0, 20}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}}, 
 FrameLabel \[RightArrow] {Style["t", 18], Style["u,v,w", 18]}, 
 PlotLegends \[RightArrow] {"u(t)", "v(t)", "w(t)"}]
```

[image]

Comment: The first error is caused because you have set u=0.618. Then you try to define a function u[t]. But this means 0.618[t] which doesn't make any sense. Go to the help page for NDSolve and try to mimic the examples there.

Comment: There are two kinds of problems in your equations. First, the syntax of the equations is wrong. For example your first equation should look like this: `D[u[t, x], t] == 
 d1*D[u[t, x], x, x] - u[t, x]*v[t, x]^2 - u[t, x]*w[t, x]^2 +F (1 - u[t, x])`. Here `d1` will play a role of the diffusion coefficient. Second, you have the partial differential equation and must, therefore, fix the boundary conditions. Third, in this case, in the NDSolve function, you should integrate also over x, rather than only over t. And finally, in Plot you also need to plot both over t and  x intervals.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch
Dear, I have already worked on your suggestion, I really didn't get anything. can you please help me with the NDSolve part to integrate over x any t.

Comment: @ Albert Dear Albert, I think your equations are written in the wrong way. The expression `D1[u[t,x],x,x]` does not seem to make sense. Please have a look into Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/NDSolve and carefully go through all examples given there. You will find there equations close to your ones. You will see what I have in mind. After you fix the equations we will possibly be able to help you further.  It is only up to you to fix these errors since it is only you who knows what you want to achieve, not me.